# Como funciona essa função de jQuery

Tags: jquery

Estou com dúvida como essa função esta funcionando. Ela tem função de quando alguém pelo iphone click no link ele não fica em houver e sim direto para link.

```
demo.autoclick = function() { 
    $('a').on('tap', function(e) {
        var el = $(this);
        var link = el.attr('href');
        window.location = link;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lendo na [documentação do jQuery mobile](https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/):

> **tap** event
>   **Description**: Triggered after a quick, complete touch event.

Ou seja, é um evento que funciona para móveis como o clique funciona para o browser. Internamente ele escuta o `touchstart` e o `touchend` e que não houve `touchmove` para ter certeza que é só um toque ("tap") em algum elemento.

Depois dentro dessa callback o `this` é o elemento clicado. Depois o código vai buscar o atributo `href` desse elemento e redireciona a página para essa url.